# ClientBundle, CssResource - how monitor load progress?

Tags: gwt

I want calculate something past css style applying. My behavior is that compiled file is loaded async, independently of call sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/)?

> Using Speed Tracer you are able to get a better picture of where time is being spent in your application. This includes problems caused by JavaScript parsing and execution, layout, CSS style recalculation and selector matching, DOM event handling, network resource loading, timer fires, XMLHttpRequest callbacks, painting, and more.

Comment: Performance is not my problem. I have whole layout in one ClientREsource and some gwt modules. Problem occured in one of them where i try calculate something based on css. Css is not present on that time. I search for method of using resources module with load monitoring.